# Problem installing EBU R128 loudness-scanner

Tags: cmake, installation

I'm a master student working on my master thesis, which require to extract loudness and pitch data each second.
I did some research and found that loudness-scanner might be able to do that.

https://github.com/jiixyj/loudness-scanner

After installing, I typed in below command, but I kept seeing this `command not found` message.

```
MacBook-Air:loudness-scanner jhl$ loudness tag 00.1mp3

-bash: loudness: command not found
```

I believe it happened because loudness-scanner didn't successfully install on my laptop, so I went back to start installing again, then ran into below error message.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    utils


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "ebur128/ebur128" which is not an existing
  directory.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "scanner" which is not an existing directory.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (to_yes_no):
  Unknown CMake command "to_yes_no".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I guess I faced this issue because I'm all new to this and some file or program are missing and needed to be installed. But I'm not sure which are missing.
Please kindly help, thank you!

Comment: Did you run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` before you tried invoking cmake?

Comment: @Botje I tried as below but didn't work

Comment: jhlde-MacBook-Air:~ jhl$ mkdir build

mkdir: build: File exists

jhlde-MacBook-Air:~ jhl$ cd build

jhlde-MacBook-Air:build jhl$ git submodule init

jhlde-MacBook-Air:build jhl$ git submodule update

jhlde-MacBook-Air:build jhl$ cmake ..

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    utils


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "ebur128/ebur128" which is not an existing
  directory.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "scanner" which is not an existing directory.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (to_yes_no):
  Unknown CMake command "to_yes_no".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/jhl/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Comment: Sorry if the note is messy, I'm all new to stack overflow as well, don't know how to put them in different lines

Comment: You can edit your question with what you have now instead of trying to cram everything into comments.

Comment: Also, you may need to nuke  your build directory and try again. CMake sometimes caches information.